# <field>__in=[None, ...] not working with ForeignKey(..., null=True)

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Distributor(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
  ...
```

I have two kinds of distributors: global distributors with user=None and distributors associated to a particular user.  I have a global distributor foo with user=None.  I can get foo with:

```
>>> d = Distributor.objects.get(user=None,name='foo')
>>> d
<Distributor: foo>
>>> d.user == None
True
```

Suppose I have a user cotton logged in.  I want to search for all distributors with user=None or user=cotton.  My idea was to use `Distributor.objects.filter(user__in=[None,cotton])`.  However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
 >>> d = Distributor.objects.get(user__in=[cotton,None],name='foo')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
 DoesNotExist: Distributor matching query does not exist.
```

Surprisingly, `get(user=None, ...)` works while `get(user__in=[None], ...)` fails.  What am I doing wrong?  Should I not expect this to work?

For the moment I got around this by creating an extra user to store the global instances.  This is with sqlite3 on a development instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `__isnull` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull:

```
Distributor.objects.get(
    Q(user__isnull=True) | Q(user__in=[cotton]), name='foo')
```

Comment: OK, great, this works and it lets me get rid of the extra user.  But is there a reason why the original code didn't work?

Comment: @CottonSeed django cant find user for None in list so i think passing user__in=[cotton, None] is equal to passing user__in=[cotton]